# Form.Show() called from a console freezes the GUI

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to instantiate a Form directly from a Console App.
For some weird reason, when I call `Form1.Show()` the newly created Form doesn't draw all its controls and Freezes (HourGlass icon). However, when I call ShowDialog(), everything goes fine, except that I need to go back to Console but I can't, so it is not an option...
What should I do to make my Form display correctly ? Am I missing something here ?

```
OrderControlForm OrderControlBox = new OrderControlForm();
OrderControlBox.BuyEvent += new OrderControl.BuyDelegate(doBuy);
OrderControlBox.SellEvent += new OrderControl.SellDelegate(doSell);
OrderControlBox.Show();
```

The above code is called in response to a command entered by the Console user.

**EDIT :** 
Here is the working code :

```
        Thread mThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            StratControlBox = new StratControl(StratIDs);
            StratControlBox.ShowDialog();
        });

        mThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        mThread.Start();
```

I still don't see why I had to call `ShowDialog()` rather than `Show()`.
When I use the latter the Form just "disappears" instantly after paint.

Comment: it depends how you calling it please show code

Comment: it is a pretty straightforward & basic form call. See edit.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a normal Windows Application template?

Comment: It is legacy code and it is mainly a Console App. I just want to open a form beside the Console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is because `ShowDialog` performs its own message loop, whereas `Show` does not.  Instead of calling `Show`, you would need to call `Application.Run`, which performs a message loop.  However, since it synchronously loops, processing incoming window messages until the form is closed, it will be effectively no different than calling `ShowDialog`.

Therefore, if you want to show the form asynchronously, you would need to do so from another thread.  However, just to be safe, make sure the new thread uses apartment threading by calling `newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`.

Also, I'd recommend only showing one main form from one UI thread.  If that main form shows other forms from its own thread, that's fine, but, if you start trying to show multiple forms, each from their own thread, it can cause problems.

**Regarding Your Update**

The reason that calling `Show` from the thread does not work is two-fold.  First, it is synchronous, so it does not return until the form is closed.  That is important because as soon as execution leaves your anonymous method, the thread will terminate.  So, when you call `Show`, it immediately returns, then leaves your method thereby terminating the thread.

Second, even if the form did stay open, it would be unresponsive, just as before, for all the same reasons.  WinForms require a message loop that keeps looking for new incoming window messasges and processing them.  The message loop calls a method called `WndProc`.  Without a message loop calling the `WndProc` method to process the incoming window messages, the form will be totally unresponsive to users.  For instance, when the mouse driver notifies windows that the user has pressed the mouse button, windows will then posts a `WM_MOUSEDOWN` message to your application's message queue.  If you don't have code somewhere that is constantly looping looking to see if there are any messages in the queue and acting upon them, you'll never get the mouse down event.

As I mentioned above, the `ShowDialog` method performs its own message loop, so it works, but `Show` does not.  `Show` assumes that it is being called by an already running message loop.  If for some reason you don't want to call `ShowDialog`, you can call `Application.Run(StratControlBox)`, instead.  The `Run` method will show the form for you and then stay in a message loop until the form is closed.  Therefore, it is a synchronous call, just like `ShowDialog`, so your thread won't terminate until the form is closed.

Comment: This sounds nice. I tried doing this but got some hectic cross-thread error messages. I'll try this tomorrow at dawn and mark this as an answer if it works (cross fingers). Keep U posted. Thanx

Comment: @MikaJacobi The cross-thread error messages are because you're attempting to access UI objects from the non-UI thread. You need to call `Control.Invoke` (blocking) or `Control.BeginInvoke` (non-blocking) to execute code on the UI thread (code which can then access the UI elements). A `Form` is a `Control` by the way (that is it also contains those methods).

Comment: "The technical, under-the-hood name for that message loop is the WndProc"... absolutely not.  The window procedure is called inside the message loop, but the window procedure is not a message loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt Point taken.  Thanks for the clarification.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> What should I do to make my Form display correctly ? Am I missing something here ?

The problem is that a Console application is not a Windows Application, and doesn't have the appropriate "plumbing" to process windows messages.  Without this, the form can't process items correctly, including the basic messages to "draw", etc.

This is handled normally by using `Application.Run` to start the message processing.  However, this blocks until the form closes (so the console won't continue to "run").  The way to handle this is to move your console code into a separate thread, and use `Application.Run` with your form like a normal windows application.

Comment: Yup, right, indeed. I just wanted to avoid re-engineering the whole stuff the other way round.

Answer (score -1):

In .NET 4.7, I was able to simply change

```
myForm.Show()
```

to

```
Task.Run(() => { myForm.ShowDialog(); });
```

I was already using

```
[STAThread] 
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

because of some other requirements.