# In C# Form freezes when opened from callback

Tags: c#, forms, callback, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a C# apps with callback functions.
When the app gets a message, a callback function is triggered and opens a form to display the contents of the message. I do that with .Show() and .BringToFront().
But the new form window, that is opened is frozen. I can't click buttons or even close the window. It remains in the background.
Can somebody tell me why this is happening?
I am using visual studio 2019.

The callback function:

```
public void currentSelectedCharacteristic_ValueChanged3(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {
                Allgemein.HinweisFenster.Show();
                Allgemein.HinweisFenster.BringToFront();                   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

We need more details to solve. But i can say that there is a process that blocks your main thread. Try to use 'Application.DoEvent();' or move your code that blocks your thread to another thread. And consider using 'background worker' for this.

Comment: I already use 'Application.DoEvent();'. Before this, the values of the messages wouldn't be written to the new form, but the freezing problem remains.
How can i know what part of the code blocks my thread?

Comment: Where are your messages coming from? From a device(via usb or serial)? Do you use a library to process or receive them? Maybe there is a recursive loop that blocks the thread. You should investigate it and move them to background worker.

Comment: The messages come via BluetoothLE, which is implemented using the WDK bluetooth libraries. So I use the libraries for receiving the messages. There are no recursive loops, which could block the thread

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420717/form-show-called-from-a-console-freezes-the-gui) for more details.
You should also consider that for Windows application, you have to be aware of threads manipulation, thus you have always one GUI thread that can be impacted by your calls flow.
So a rule of thumb is to know how your threads work inside your application.
Generally speaking, Frozen windows are often a sign of **GUI thread block**.

Comment: The form is actually created earlier in the code. During the callback I only use .show() to bring it up. I even tried creating a new instance of the form, which didnt help. 
Following the thread you linked, I tried to create a new thread, which opens the form. This didnt help either